# Printing individual letters in a list

Tags: python, string, list, console-application, acronym

I am writing a program that takes a statement or phrase from a user and converts it to an acronym.

It should look like:

```
Enter statement here:
> Thank god it's Friday
Acronym : TGIF
```

The best way I have found to accomplish this is through a list and using `.split()` to separate each word into its own string and am able to isolate the first letter of the first item, however when I try to modify the program for the following items by changing to print statement to:

print("Acronym :", x[0:][0])

it just ends up printing the entirety of the letters in the first item.

Here's what I have gotten so far, however it only prints the first letter of the first item...

```
acroPhrase = str(input("Enter a sentence or phrase : "))     
acroPhrase = acroPhrase.upper()  

x = acroPhrase.split(" ")  
    print("Acronym :", x[0][0])
```

Comment: Please be sure to tag your question with the programming language in use not only to make that clear but also so it will [be seen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) by the users best able to help you.  Whatever the language (JavaScript?), `x` should be an array/list of the words in `acroPhrase`, `x[0]` should be the first _word_ in `acroPhrase`, and the first _character_ of the first _word_ in `acroPhrase` will be something like `x[0][0]`.  You'll need a loop (explicit or otherwise) to assemble one character from each word into an acronym.

Comment: That makes more sense. Forgot to tag the language, will be sure to do so in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try using a comprehension or a loop in order to do something with each of the words `in` x?

Comment: Yes, ended up using a for loop in the end. I hadn't fully understood this sort of loop, but after a few google searches into what it was and how it works, it made much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.sub` with a callback we can try:

```py
inp = "Peas porridge hot"
output = re.sub(r'(\S)\S*', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), inp)
print(output)  # PPH
```

Answer (score 2):

The code needs to iterate through the `.split` result. For example, using a list comprehension:

```
inp = "Thank god its friday"
inp = inp.split()
first_lets = [word[0] for word in inp]
```

Comment: Please don't use conversational language in answers - this is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2):

```
acroPhrase = str(input("Enter a sentence or phrase : "))     
acroPhrase = acroPhrase.upper()  

x = acroPhrase.split(" ")  
result = ''
for i in x:
    word = list(i)
    result+=word[0]

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't thought about the logic in this way